# How to approach writing developer tests (unit tests, integration tests, etc) for a system?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing, service, tdd

I have a WCF service which runs and interacts with database, file system and few external web services, then creates the result and Xml Serialize it and returns it finally.

I'd like to write tests for this solution and I'm thinking how (it's all using dependency injection and design by contract).

There are 3 main approaches I can take.

1) I can pick smallest units of codes/methods and write tests for it. Pick one class and isolate it from its dependencies (other classes, etc). Although it guarantees quality but it takes lots of time writing them and that's slow.

2) Only make the interaction with external systems mockable and write some tests that cover the main scenarios from when the request is made until the response is serialized and returned. This will test all the interactions between my classes but mocks all external resource accesses.

3) I can setup a test environment where the interaction with external web services do happen, file access happens, database access happens, etc. Then writing the tests from end to end. this requires environmental setup and dependency on all other systems to be up and running.

About #1, I see no point in investing the time/money/energy on writing the tests for every single method or codes that I have. I mean it's a waste of time.

About #3, since it has dependency on external resources/systems, it's hard to set it up and running.

#2, sounds to be the best option to me. Since it will test what it should be testing. Only my system and all its classes and mocking all other external systems.

So basically, my conclusion after some years experience with unit tests is that writing unit tests is a waste to be avoided and instead isolated system tests are best return on investment.

Even if I was going to write the tests first (TDD) then the production code, still #2 I think would be best.

What's your view on this? would you write small unit tests for your application? would you consider it a good practice and best use of time/budget/energy?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to talk about *quality*, you should have all 3:

1. Unit tests to ensure your code does what you think it does, expose any edge cases and help with [regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression). You (developer) should write such tests.
2. Integration tests to verify correctness of entire process, whether components *talk* to each other correctly and so on. And again, you as a developer write such tests.
3. System-wide tests in production-like environment (with some limitations naturally - you might not have access to client database, but you should have its *exact* copy on your local machines). Those tests are usually written by dedicated testers (often in programming languages different from application code), but of course can be written by you.

Second and third type of tests (integration and system) will be way too much effort to test *edge cases* of smaller components. This is what you usually want unit tests for. You need integration because something might fail on hooking-up of tested, verified and correct modules. And of course system tests is what you do daily, during development, or have assigned people (manual testers) do it.

Going for selected type of tests from the list might work to some point, but is far from complete solution or quality software.

Comment: Having exact copies of client data on local dev machines is a very bad idea from a security/privacy perspective.

Comment: @DanielS. - of course. If you don't have access to client database, it's hard to make exact copy of data, right? *Exact copy* refers to structure and relations between data. You can achieve that without any sensitive/real information.

Answer (score 1):

All 3 are important and targeted at different test types that is a matrix of unit/integration/system categories with positive and negative testing in each category.

For code coverage Unit testing will yield the highest percentage, followed by Integration then System.

You also need to consider whether or not the purpose of the test is Validation (will meet the final user\customer requirements, i.e Value) or Verification (written to specification, i.e. Correct).

In summary the answer is 'it depends', and I would recommend following the SEI CMMi model for Verification and Validation (i.e. testing) which begins with the goals (value) of each activity then subjecting that activity to measures that will ultimately allow the whole process to be subjected to continuous improvement. In this way you have isolated the What and Why from the How and you will be able to answer time and value type questions for your given environment (which could be a Life support System or a Tweet of the day, to your favorite Aunt, App).

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**:  #2 (integration testing) seems most logical, but you shouldn't hesitate to use a variety of tests to achieve the best coverage for pieces of your codebase that need it most.  Shooting for having tests for "everything" is not a worthy goal.

**Long version**

There is a school of thought out there where devs are convinced that adopting unit\integration\system tests means striving for every single chuck of code being tested.  It's either no test coverage at all, or committing to testing "everything".  This binary thinking always makes adopting any kind of testing strategy seem very expensive.

The truth is, forcing every single line of code\function\module to be tested is about as sound as writing all your code to be as fast as possible.  It takes too much time and effort, and most of it nets very little return.  Another truth is that you can never achieve true 100% coverage in a non-trivial project.

Testing is not a goal unto itself.  It's a means to achieve other things:  final product quality, maintainability, interoperability, and so on, all while expending the least amount of effort possible.

With that in mind, step back and evaluate your particular circumstances.  Why do you want to "write tests for this solution"?  Are you unhappy with the overall quality of the project today?  Have you experienced high regression rates?  Are you perhaps unsure about how some module works (and more importantly, what bugs it might have)?  Regardless of what your exact goal is, you should be able to select pieces that pose particular challenges and focus your attention on them.  Depending on what those pieces are, an appropriate testing approach can be selected.

If you have a particularly tricky function or a class, consider unit testing them.  If you're faced with a complicated architecture with multiple, hard to understand interactions, consider writing integration tests to establish a clean baseline for your trickiest scenarios and to better understand where the problems are coming from (you'll probably flush out some bugs along the way).  System testing can help if your concerns are not addressed in more localized tests.

Based on the information you provided for your particular scenario, external-facing unit testing\integration testing (#2) looks most promising.  It seems like you have a lot of external dependencies, so I'd guess this is where most of the complexity hides.  Comprehensive unit testing (#1) is a superset of #2, with all the extra internal stuff carrying questionable value.  #3 (full system testing) will probably not allow you to test external edge cases\error conditions as well as you would like.